# PHP PDO counting all table rows in Database

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo, sum

This MYSQL statement is functioning in MYSQL.

```
SELECT SUM(TABLE_ROWS) 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES 
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'sample'
```

But when I put into my PHP code it does not funtion. What am I gonna do? The image below encircled with red is what I want to output in my page. Thank you.

[image]

Comment: What does it do when you run it? That query is fine. How do you execute it?

Comment: Are the credentials you use in phpmyadmin the same as for php? You may be using incorrect permissions

Comment: @Hanky yeah totally fine. I execute it as it is `<?php 
                                     $stmt = $conn->query('SELECT SUM(TABLE_ROWS) 
                                        FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES 
                                        WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = sample
                                        ');
                                     $row_count = $stmt->rowCount();
                                     echo $row_count; 

                                    ?>`

Comment: @Terminus that is Im thinking haha :D

Comment: `rowCount()` ? no this will return only one row. So you have to fetch the result and see what `SUM(TABLE_ROWS)` contains

Comment: my database name is `sample`. This is the error when I run **Unknown column 'sample' in 'where clause'**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code looks fine, but in comment you wrote that where clause in your query looks like:

`WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = sample`,  but it's incorrect because `sample` must be passed like `'string'`.

Here my code, and it works:

```
<?php

$dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=myDB', 'myUser', 'myPass');
$sth = $dbh->prepare("
    SELECT SUM(TABLE_ROWS) AS totalRowsCount
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES 
    WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'myDB'
");
$sth->execute();
$result = $sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
var_export($result);
```

and as result will be:

```
[0 => ['totalRowsCount' => '125']]
```

Comment: i got it alreay haha. I almost having 4-5 hours of finding an answer to this matter. so our time is already 1:55pm PHIL time. anyways fetchAll is kinda for array therefore we'll be using `foreach($result[0] as $child) {
   echo $child . "\n";
}` to output in a nice way.

`**output now will be:**
125`

Thanks Vladimir. and all the guys there. :)

Comment: You also can use `$result = $sth->fetchColumn();`.

Comment: You may add a note that this code would work [only when emulation mode is turned on](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo#emulation)